# Android EditText to int in inner class

Tags: java, android, timer

So I'm getting one tricky problem when trying to decrement value of EditText. Let me explain, I have some CountDownTimers and when second timer gets to the end a value that's setted before needs to be decremented so the timers won't repeat infinite amount of times.

Here's my code:

```
public void poslijeDelaya() {

                int counterInt = Integer.parseInt(editTextNOI.getText().toString());

                if (counterInt > 0) {


                    String tekstTrci = editTextHIIVrijeme.getText().toString();
                    long longTrci = Long.parseLong(tekstTrci);

                    CountDownTimer timerTrci = new CountDownTimer(longTrci * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            textViewGlavniTimer.setText("00:00");
                            textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.liiState));

                            String tekstHodaj = editTextLIIVrijeme.getText().toString();
                            long longHodaj = Long.parseLong(tekstHodaj);

                            CountDownTimer timerHodaj = new CountDownTimer(longHodaj * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
                                @Override
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    counterInt --;
                                    textViewGlavniTimer.setText("00:00");
                                    textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hiiState));
                                    poslijeDelaya();

                                }
                            }.start();

                        }
                    }.start();
                } else {
                    textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText("Done");
                }
            }
        });
```

The tricky part is on `counterInt --;` part. It says that the variable needs to be declared as final because it's accessed from inner class so I set `int counterInt = Integer.parseInt(editTextNOI.getText().toString());` to `final int counterInt = Integer.parseInt(editTextNOI.getText().toString());` and guess what?

It says that it can't assign value to a final variable.

Any ideas on how to make Android Studio to stop trolling me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THE SOLUTION:

```
int counterInt; // as a global variable



counterInt = Integer.parseInt(editTextNOI.getText().toString()); // in onCreate()



 public void poslijeDelaya(final int count) {

                if (counterInt > 0) {


                    String tekstTrci = editTextHIIVrijeme.getText().toString();
                    long longTrci = Long.parseLong(tekstTrci);

                    textViewRundiPreostalo.setText(Integer.toString(counterInt));
                    CountDownTimer timerTrci = new CountDownTimer(longTrci * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            textViewGlavniTimer.setText("00:00");
                            imageViewSlikaZaOpisAktivnosti.setImageResource(R.drawable.timer_niski_intenzitet);
                            textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.liiState));
                            String tekstHodaj = editTextLIIVrijeme.getText().toString();
                            long longHodaj = Long.parseLong(tekstHodaj);

                            CountDownTimer timerHodaj = new CountDownTimer(longHodaj * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
                                @Override
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    textViewGlavniTimer.setText("00:00");
                                    textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hiiState));
                                    counterInt--;
                                    poslijeDelaya(counterInt);
                                }
                            }.start();

                        }
                    }.start();
                } else {
                    textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText("Done");
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make `counterInt` as a member variable and you are good to go.

```
private int counterInt;
```

Assign the value whenever you want.

Also, move `counterInt = Integer.parseInt(editTextNOI.getText().toString());` outside `poslijeDelaya()`.

Comment: Tried this before, it keeps repeating forever

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `int` a class variable, but then you could run in to problems where the value is accesses from more than one thread. Instead, make the `int` class level in the `CountDownTimer` class. Like this:

```
 CountDownTimer timerTrci = new CountDownTimer(longTrci * 1000 + 100, 1000) {

                        int counterInt = Integer.parseInt(editTextNOI.getText().toString()); <---- add your variable here

                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            ...
                        }

                        ....
                        CountDownTimer timerHodaj = new CountDownTimer(longHodaj * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                counterInt --;  <-- now this is accessible  
                                ....
                            }
                        }.start();
                        }
                    }.start();
```

Comment: Wait, this wont work. I just noticed your last line `poslijeDelaya();` which will call this method recursively.

Comment: try my other answer. It may help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it helps, when you add a new method in your super class for decrementing the counterInt and then just call this method in onFinish()?

Answer (score 1):

After reading your code further, I realize my previous answer wont work because you are calling the method recursively. So instead try this:

```
public void poslijeDelaya(final int count) {
                if (counterInt > 0) {

                    String tekstTrci = editTextHIIVrijeme.getText().toString();
                    long longTrci = Long.parseLong(tekstTrci);

                    CountDownTimer timerTrci = new CountDownTimer(longTrci * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
                        @Override
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                            updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFinish() {
                            textViewGlavniTimer.setText("00:00");
                            textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.liiState));

                            String tekstHodaj = editTextLIIVrijeme.getText().toString();
                            long longHodaj = Long.parseLong(tekstHodaj);

                            CountDownTimer timerHodaj = new CountDownTimer(longHodaj * 1000 + 100, 1000) {
                                @Override
                                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                    updateTimer((int) millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFinish() {
                                    textViewGlavniTimer.setText("00:00");
                                    textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.hiiState));
                                    poslijeDelaya(counterInt - 1);

                                }
                            }.start();

                        }
                    }.start();
                } else {
                    textViewNatpisZaOpisAktivnosti.setText("Done");
                }
            }
        });
```

Then, call initially like this:

```
int counterInt = Integer.parseInt(editTextNOI.getText().toString());
poslijeDelaya(counterInt);
```

Comment: Hmm, now after that delay that I set it just skips if statement and outputs "Done" on my TextView

Comment: But this fixed your problem accessing your `counterInt` variable?